# Is it possible to use a destructuring assignment for an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, destructuring

Say I have the following:

```
const db = {players: [{elo:3}, {elo:4}]}
```

I can do this

```
const [white, black] = db.players
```

But what if I want to get the elo fields? I can do this:

```
const [{elo:elo1}, {elo:elo2}] = db.players
```

It would be cleaner to combine the two, but neither this:

```
const [white:{elo}, black:{elo}] = db.players
```

nor this:

```
const [{elo}:white, {elo}:black] = db.players
```

Is syntactically correct. Is there a way to destructure a subset of fields in an array of objects in one line?

Comment: Any reason you don't just use `const [{elo:white}, {elo:black}] = db.players` which is the "But what if I want to get the elo fields? I can do this:" but with the white/black you want instead of elo1/elo2?

Comment: In destructuring you put the variables you're assigning where the values are in the literal, not where the property names are.

Comment: You can use rest syntax to get _some of_ an object, if that's what you mean: `const [{ ...white }, { ...black }] = db.players`. This would allow you to also list properties you _didn't_ want in the result.

Comment: "any reason you don't just use const [{elo:white}, {elo:black}]..."
What if there are multiple fields? then that simple naming convention gets messy

Comment: I think the simplest is to destructure the array in a for loop

Comment: It really boils down to "I want to select subfields as a named object" but I don't think a destrcturing assignment can do that.

Comment: I don't quite get what the expected outcome is then. You've shown things that *don't work* and the only one that *does* you claim doesn't do what you want. So...what *should* be happening? What result are you expecting to get out of this?

Comment: I thought I was clear in my response: if there are multiple fields to retrieve (not just one), then renaming each field doesn't work; i.e. [{elo, name}: white]  isn't valid.